# Improvements for Java Code of a Fruit and Vegetable Management Application

Tags: java

I have developed a Java application as per a specific assignment, which includes features for adding, searching, and removing fruit and vegetable products. I would like a review of my code in terms of best practices and any possible improvements. I also have some specific questions:

How can I enhance error handling and user feedback in my program?

Is there a way to optimize my code to avoid code repetition in the user interface?

Are there any other ways to organize my code to make it more modular and easier to understand?

What improvements can I make to enhance the usability of my program?

I appreciate any comments and suggestions that can help me improve my code and my understanding of Java programming. Thank you!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static ArrayList<Product> allFruitsandVegetables = new ArrayList<Product>();

    static String [] menyOptions = {"\n1. Add a product.",
                                    "2. Search the catalog.",
                                    "3. Browse the catalog.",
                                    "4. Remove a product.",
                                    "5. Print all products",
                                    "6. Exit the program"};
    static String [] catalogOptions = { "1. Browse the catalog.",
                                        "2. Search the catalog.",
                                        "3. Go back to the main menu."};


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Banan", 10.50, "kg",  "Frukt" , "Rund" ));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Äpple", 5.64, "pcs" , "Frukt" , "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Päron",6.55, "pcs", "Frukt" , "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Jordgubb", 7.95, "st" ,"Frukt" , "Bär"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Mango", 5.77 ,"pcs", "Frukt" , "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Kiwi" , 4.67 ,"pcs", "Frukt" , "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Gurka" , 12.0 ,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Lång"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Tomat", 7.54 ,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Broccoli" , 6.33,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Vitkål", 45.65,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Morot" , 6.70,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Kålrot" , 3.55,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Champinjon" , 4.22,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Svamp"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Kantarell" , 10.77,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Svamp" ));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Karl-Johan", 3.56,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Svamp"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Potatis" , 3.99,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Aubergine", 13.44,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Svart"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Zucchini" , 11.98,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Svart"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Gul lök", 2.33 ,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Lök" ));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(new Product("Röd lök" , 2.55,"pcs", "Grönsak", "Lök"));

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Fruit and Vegetable program.");
        System.out.print("Please enter any key to continue to the meny.");
        boolean quitProgram= false;
        String employeeInput = input.nextLine();

        do {
            for (String listOfOptions : menyOptions){
                System.out.println(listOfOptions);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter one of the following numbers to continue: ");

            try {

                int employeeInput2 = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                switch (employeeInput2){
                    case 1 -> addFruitOrVegetable();
                    case 2 -> searchTheCatalog();
                    case 3 -> browseTheCatalog();
                    case 4 -> removeProduct();
                    case 5 -> printAllProducts();
                    case 6 -> quitProgram = true;
                    default -> System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid, please enter a number between 1-6. ");
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid, you cannot enter a letter, please enter a number.");
                input.nextLine();
            }

        } while (quitProgram == false);
        System.out.println("\nThank you for using the Fruit and Vegetable program.");
        System.out.println("All credit goes to Kerem Incorporated.");

    }

    public static void addFruitOrVegetable (){
        double userSetPrice = 0.0;
        String userSetPricePerPcsOrKg = "";
        String userSetFruitOrVegetable = "";
        String userSetProductType = "";

        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the name of the product: ");
        String userSetName = input.nextLine();
        Product createdUserProduct = new Product(userSetName, 0, "", "", "");
        System.out.print("Do you want to add price? Please write yes or any key to continue: ");
        String userChoicePrice = input.nextLine();
        if (userChoicePrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
            System.out.print("Please enter a price: ");
            userSetPrice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter if price is per piece (pcs) or per kilogram (kg). Write pcs or kg: ");
            userSetPricePerPcsOrKg = input.nextLine();
            createdUserProduct = new Product(userSetName, userSetPrice, userSetPricePerPcsOrKg, "", "");
        }
        System.out.print("Do you want add if product is a fruit or vegetable? Please write yes or any key to continue: ");
        String userChoiceFruitOrVegetable = input.nextLine();
        if (userChoiceFruitOrVegetable.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.print("Please enter if product is a fruit or vegetable: ");
            userSetFruitOrVegetable = input.nextLine();
            createdUserProduct = new Product(userSetName, userSetPrice, userSetPricePerPcsOrKg, userSetFruitOrVegetable, "");
        }
        System.out.print("Do you want to add the producttype? Please write yes or any key to continue: ");
        String userChoiceProductType = input.nextLine();
        if (userChoiceProductType.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
            System.out.print("Please enter the producttype: ");
            userSetProductType = input.nextLine();

        }
        createdUserProduct = new Product(userSetName, userSetPrice, userSetPricePerPcsOrKg, userSetFruitOrVegetable, userSetProductType);
        System.out.print("\n\033[1mYou added: \033[0m");
        System.out.print(createdUserProduct.toString());
        System.out.println("");
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(createdUserProduct);
    }

    public static void searchTheCatalog() {
        boolean runSearchCatalog = false;

        do {
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter a keyword: ");
            String searchTerm = input.nextLine().trim();

            if (searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("\nPlease enter a valid keyword to search.");
                return;
            }

            boolean resultFoundInCatalog = false;

            for (Product catalog : allFruitsandVegetables) {
                if (catalog.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                    System.out.println("\n\033[1mThe result of your search:\033[0m");
                    System.out.println(catalog.toString());
                    System.out.println("\nDo you want to calculate price for the product?");
                    System.out.print("Please enter yes to accept or any key to continue: ");
                    String userChoiceYesOrNo = input.nextLine();
                    if (userChoiceYesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter quantity: ");
                        double userChoiceQuantity = input.nextDouble();
                        input.nextLine();
                        calculatePrice(userChoiceQuantity, catalog.getPrice());
                    }
                    resultFoundInCatalog = true;
                }
            }
            if (!resultFoundInCatalog) {
                System.out.println("\nNo search results found.");
            }
            System.out.print("Do you want to exit to the main menu? Write Yes/No: ");
            String exitSearchCatalog = input.nextLine();
            if (exitSearchCatalog.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                runSearchCatalog = true;
            }

        } while (runSearchCatalog == false);
    }

    public static void browseTheCatalog () {
        boolean quitCatalog = false;
        ArrayList<String> allUniqueItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> allUniqueItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> allUniqueItems3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to the product catalog, do you want to:");
        do {
            for (String browsingCatalog : catalogOptions) {
                System.out.println(browsingCatalog);
            }
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            int userCatalogChoice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            if (userCatalogChoice == 1) {
                allUniqueItems.clear();
                for (Product uniqueItem : allFruitsandVegetables) {
                    boolean doesItemExist = false;
                    for (String t : allUniqueItems) {
                        if (t.equals(uniqueItem.getFruitOrVegetable())) {
                            doesItemExist = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!doesItemExist) {
                        allUniqueItems.add(uniqueItem.getFruitOrVegetable());
                    }
                    doesItemExist = false;
                }
                System.out.println("\nCategory options: ");
                for (String primaryTypes : allUniqueItems) {
                    System.out.println(primaryTypes);
                }
                System.out.print("\nPlease choose from the options: ");
                String firstUserCatalogChoice = input.nextLine();

                if(allUniqueItems.contains(firstUserCatalogChoice)){
                    for (Product uniqueItem2 : allFruitsandVegetables) {
                        if (uniqueItem2.getFruitOrVegetable().equals(firstUserCatalogChoice)) {
                            boolean doesItemExist = false;
                            for (String t2 : allUniqueItems2) {
                                if (t2.equals(uniqueItem2.getProductType())) {
                                    doesItemExist = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!doesItemExist) {
                                allUniqueItems2.add(uniqueItem2.getProductType());

                            }
                            doesItemExist = false;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\nCategory options: ");
                    for (String secondaryTypes : allUniqueItems2) {
                        System.out.println(secondaryTypes);
                    }
                    System.out.print("\nPlease choose from the options: ");
                    String firstUserCatalogChoice2 = input.nextLine();
                    if (allUniqueItems2.contains(firstUserCatalogChoice2)){
                        System.out.println("\n\033[1mFull products: \033[0m");
                        for (Product fullProduct : allFruitsandVegetables){
                            if (fullProduct.getProductType().equals(firstUserCatalogChoice2)){
                                System.out.println(fullProduct.toString());
                                System.out.println("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (userCatalogChoice == 2) {
                searchTheCatalog();
            }
            else if (userCatalogChoice == 3) {
                quitCatalog = true;
            }
        } while (!quitCatalog);
    }


    public static void removeProduct(){
        boolean runRemoveProduct = false;

        do {
            boolean doesProductExist = false;
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter the name of the product you want to remove: ");
            String userChoice = input.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < allFruitsandVegetables.size(); i++) {
                if (allFruitsandVegetables.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(userChoice)) {
                    Product removedProduct = allFruitsandVegetables.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("You removed " + removedProduct.getName() + ".");
                    doesProductExist = true;
                }
            }
            if (!doesProductExist){
                System.out.println("\nThis product does not exist.");
            }
            System.out.print("Type yes to exit or any key to begin again: ");
            String userChoiceToExit = input.nextLine();
            if (userChoiceToExit.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                runRemoveProduct = true;
            }

        }while (runRemoveProduct == false);


    }

    public static void printAllProducts(){
        for(Product allProducts : allFruitsandVegetables){
            System.out.println(allProducts);
        }
    }

    public static void calculatePrice(double quantity, double price){
        double sum = quantity * price;
        System.out.println("The total price will be: " + sum + " kr.");
    }

}


    
    public class Product {
        private String name;
        private double price;
    
        private String pricePerPcsOrKg;
        private String fruitOrVegetable;
        private String productType;
    
    
        public Product (String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public Product (String name, double price){
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public Product (String name, double price, String pricePerPcsOrKg, String fruitOrVegetable, String productType){
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.pricePerPcsOrKg = pricePerPcsOrKg;
            this.fruitOrVegetable = fruitOrVegetable;
            this.productType = productType;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    
        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public String getPricePerPcsOrKg() {
            return pricePerPcsOrKg;
        }
    
        public void userSetPricePerPcsOrKg(String pricePerPcsOrKg) {
            this.pricePerPcsOrKg = pricePerPcsOrKg;
        }
    
        public String getFruitOrVegetable(){
            return fruitOrVegetable;
        }
    
        public void setFruitOrVegetable(String fruitOrVegetable){
            this.fruitOrVegetable = fruitOrVegetable;
        }
    
        public String getProductType() {
            return productType;
        }
    
        public void setProductType(String productType) {
            this.productType = productType;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\nName of the product: " + name + "\nPrice: " + price + " kr per " + pricePerPcsOrKg + "\nPrimarytype: " + fruitOrVegetable +  "\nSecondarytype: " + productType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which country? Krone suggests Sweden, Denmark or Estonia.

Comment: Ah, based on the language it's Sweden.

Comment: Yes :) .........

Answer (score 5):

## Explanation

I started to refactor your code, but the amount of code is just too much.  You should move out of the `static` realm as soon as possible.  Break your code up into bite-size methods.

One good pattern to learn is the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows you to separate your concerns and focus on one small part of the code at a time.

Here's an example of what I mean.  You already had a `Product` class.  So, I created an `Inventory` class.

```
public class Inventory {

    private final List<Product> allFruitsandVegetables;

    public Inventory() {
        this.allFruitsandVegetables = createInventory();
    }

    private List<Product> createInventory() {
        List<Product> allFruitsandVegetables = new ArrayList<>();
        
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Banan", 10.50, "kg", "Frukt", "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Äpple", 5.64, "pcs", "Frukt", "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Päron", 6.55, "pcs", "Frukt", "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Jordgubb", 7.95, "st", "Frukt", "Bär"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Mango", 5.77, "pcs", "Frukt", "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Kiwi", 4.67, "pcs", "Frukt", "Rund"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Gurka", 12.0, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Lång"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Tomat", 7.54, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Broccoli", 6.33, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Vitkål", 45.65, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Morot", 6.70, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Kålrot", 3.55, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Champinjon", 4.22, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Svamp"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Kantarell", 10.77, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Svamp"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Karl-Johan", 3.56, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Svamp"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Potatis", 3.99, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Rotfrukt"));
        allFruitsandVegetables.add(
                new Product("Aubergine", 13.44, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Svart"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Zucchini", 11.98, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Svart"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Gul lök", 2.33, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Lök"));
        allFruitsandVegetables
                .add(new Product("Röd lök", 2.55, "pcs", "Grönsak", "Lök"));
    
        return allFruitsandVegetables;
    }

    public List<Product> getAllFruitsandVegetables() {
        return allFruitsandVegetables;
    }

}
```

This isolates the inventory so the rest of your code can use the entire inventory as one large object.

Next, I broke up your main process into methods.

```
public class ProduceMain {
    
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProduceMain pm = new ProduceMain();
        pm.showIntroduction(input);
        int option = 0;
        do {
            pm.showMenu(input);
            int option = pm.displayMenu(input);
            pm.selectOption(option);
        while (option < 6);
        pm.showConclusion;
    }
    
    private final Inventory inventory;
    
    public ProduceMain() {
        this.inventory = new Inventory();
    }
    
    public void showIntroduction(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Fruit and Vegetable program.");
        System.out.print("Please enter any key to continue to the meny.");
        input.nextLine();
    }
    
    public void showMenu(Scanner input) {
        int option = 0;
        
        do {
            option = displayMenu(input);
        } while (option < 6);
    }
    
    private int displayMenu(Scanner input) {
        String[] menuOptions = { "\n1. Add a product.",
        "2. Search the catalog.", "3. Browse the catalog.",
        "4. Remove a product.", "5. Print all products",
        "6. Exit the program" };
        
        for (String listOfOptions : menuOptions) {
            System.out.println(listOfOptions);
        }
        int option = 0;
        String message = "The input is not valid, please "
                + "enter a number between 1 and 6.";
        while (option < 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter one of the menu options to continue: ");
            String response = input.nextLine();
            try {
                option = Integer.valueOf(response);
                if (option < 1 || option > 6) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                    option = 0;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
        
        return option;
    }
    
    public void selectOption(int option) {
        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            addFruitOrVegetable();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchTheCatalog();
            break;
        case 3:
            browseTheCatalog();
            break;
        case 4:
            removeProduct();
            break;
        case 5:
            printAllProducts();
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    public void showConclusion() {
        System.out.println(
                "\nThank you for using the Fruit and Vegetable program.");
        System.out.println("All credit goes to Kerem Incorporated.");
    }
}
```

The `main` method reads like an outline to the rest of your code.

I create the inventory in the class constructor.

The rest of your menu code is broken into methods.  Each method has one purpose.  Each method is bite-sized,

That's as far as I got refactoring your code.

## Questions

> How can I enhance error handling and user feedback in my program?

See the `displayMenu` method for one example.  The code will reject anything that's not the values 1 through 6.

> Is there a way to optimize my code to avoid code repetition in the
> user interface?

Use methods to isolate repetive code.  In the `displayMenu` method, I set a message to a String so I could use the message twice.

> Are there any other ways to organize my code to make it more modular
> and easier to understand?

Classes and methods.  You could put the code for each of the menu options in its own class.

> What improvements can I make to enhance the usability of my program?

I couldn't test your original code, so I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Our teacher said that we can only use a main class and a product class, we cannot add more classes, and we have to use three constructors, i should have added it in the desciption.

Comment: @KeremTazedal Those are bad requirements. Do what your teacher says for this class, but know that it's not a good idea and proper Java will look very different.

Comment: Yes, we are about 1 1/2 intro our Java course, i think the requirements are supposed to be bad. He is trying to make a point, i think.

Comment: You could  (should?) introducce an `Enum` for the options instead of the magic integer values. That can also contain the menu text and the selection-number. That way you can easily modify the menu and the code become a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

In your variable name, `meny` should be spelled `menu`.

It's not very helpful to store arrays of menu options the way you have them. You can just output a multi-line string. (Or go in the other direction and generate a list of option names to method references, rather than a hard-coded switch.)

You have a mix of English and Swedish user interface content - this seems inconsistent and should probably all be in Swedish. Java understands how to properly format regional currency, so you should at least load the locale for this purpose.

Move your initial `add`s to an array literal on a member list.

You should remove your loop exit variables like `boolean quitProgram= false;` and instead prefer `break` or `return`.

The order of these statements is backwards:

```
            for (String listOfOptions : menyOptions){
                System.out.println(listOfOptions);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter one of the following numbers to continue: ");
```

The prompt should appear before the list of options, or should be reworded.

`addFruitOrVegetable` should only construct a new `Product` once, at the end of the routine.

You should represent the produce type (fruit/vegetable) and the unit type (pcs/st/kg) as enums. Also, the option `st` is missing from some of your user interface.

For quantity, if the unit is `pcs` or `st`, do not call `nextDouble` - it's an `int`. (`kg` should still use `nextDouble`; I haven't shown this in the code below.)

You should factor out a function that asks yes/no.

`Product` should be an immutable `record`, and all of its accessors should go away.

### Suggested

This preserves the single-file format, though a good Java program would separate this into multiple files. Please forgive my Google Translate.

```java
package org.stackexchange;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public enum ProduceType {
        Fruit("Frukt"),
        Vegetable("Grönsak");

        public final String name;

        ProduceType(String name) { this.name = name; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return name; }

        public static ProduceType fromName(String name) throws NoSuchElementException {
            return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(e -> e.name.equals(name))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        }
    }

    public enum Unit {
        Piece("pcs"),
        Instance("st"),  // stycken
        Kilogram("kg");

        public final String name;

        Unit(String name) { this.name = name; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return name; }

        public static Unit fromName(String name) throws NoSuchElementException {
            return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(e -> e.name.equals(name))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        }
    }

    public record Product(
        String name,
        double price,
        Unit unit,
        ProduceType produceType,
        String secondaryType
    ) {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return """
Produktens namn: %s
Pris: %s per %s
Primär typ: %s
Sekundär typ: %s
            """.formatted(
                name, currFormat.format(price),
                unit, produceType, secondaryType);
        }

        public boolean hasTerm(String term) {
            return name.toLowerCase().contains(term.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    private static final Locale locale = new Locale.Builder()
        .setLanguage("sv")
        .setRegion("SE")
        .build();
    private static final NumberFormat currFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);


    private final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Product(     "Banan", 10.50, Unit.Kilogram, ProduceType.Fruit,     "Rund"),
        new Product(     "Äpple",  5.64, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Fruit,     "Rund"),
        new Product(     "Päron",  6.55, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Fruit,     "Rund"),
        new Product(  "Jordgubb",  7.95, Unit.Instance, ProduceType.Fruit,     "Bär"),
        new Product(     "Mango",  5.77, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Fruit,     "Rund"),
        new Product(      "Kiwi",  4.67, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Fruit,     "Rund"),
        new Product(     "Gurka", 12.00, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Lång"),
        new Product(     "Tomat",  7.54, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Rotfrukt"),
        new Product(  "Broccoli",  6.33, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Rotfrukt"),
        new Product(    "Vitkål", 45.65, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Rotfrukt"),
        new Product(     "Morot",  6.70, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Rotfrukt"),
        new Product(    "Kålrot",  3.55, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Rotfrukt"),
        new Product("Champinjon",  4.22, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Svamp"),
        new Product( "Kantarell", 10.77, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Svamp"),
        new Product("Karl-Johan",  3.56, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Svamp"),
        new Product(   "Potatis",  3.99, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Rotfrukt"),
        new Product( "Aubergine", 13.44, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Svart"),
        new Product(  "Zucchini", 11.98, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Svart"),
        new Product(   "Gul lök",  2.33, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Lök"),
        new Product(   "Röd lök",  2.55, Unit.Piece,    ProduceType.Vegetable, "Lök")
    ));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.print("""
Välkommen till programmet Frukt och grönt.
Ange valfri nyckel för att fortsätta till menyn.
""");
        input.nextLine();
        runMenu();

        System.out.print("""
Tack för att du använder programmet Frukt och grönt.
All kredit går till Kerem Inkorporerad.
""");
    }

    public void runMenu() {
        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("""
Ange ett av följande nummer för att fortsätta:
1. Lägg till en produkt.
2. Sök i katalogen.
3. Bläddra i katalogen.
4. Ta bort en produkt.
5. Skriv ut alla produkter.
6. Avsluta programmet.
""");
            switch (input.nextLine()) {
            case "1":
                addProduct();
                break;
            case "2":
                searchCatalog();
                break;
            case "3":
                browseCatalog();
                break;
            case "4":
                removeProduct();
                break;
            case "5":
                printAllProducts();
                break;
            case "6":
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("Inmatningen är inte giltig. Ange ett nummer mellan 1-6.");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean askYesNo() {
        System.out.print("Vänligen skriv ja eller valfri nyckel för att fortsätta: ");
        return "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input.nextLine());
    }

    public void addProduct() {
        System.out.print("Vänligen ange namnet på produkten: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        double price = 0.0;
        Unit unit = Unit.Piece;
        System.out.print("Vill du lägga till pris? ");
        if (askYesNo()) {
            System.out.print("Ange ett pris: ");
            price = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ange om priset är per bit (pcs), per kilogram (kg) eller per styck (st): ");
            try {
                unit = Unit.fromName(input.nextLine());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Ogiltig enhet");
            }
        }

        ProduceType produceType = ProduceType.Vegetable;
        System.out.print("Vill du lägga till om produkten är en frukt eller grönsak? ");
        if (askYesNo()) {
            System.out.print("Ange om produkten är en frukt eller grönsak: ");
            try {
                produceType = ProduceType.fromName(input.nextLine());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Ogiltig produkttyp");
            }
        }

        String productType = "";
        System.out.print("Vill du lägga till produkttypen? ");
        if (askYesNo()) {
            System.out.print("Vänligen ange produkttyp: ");
            productType = input.nextLine();
        }

        Product createdUserProduct = new Product(name, price, unit, produceType, productType);
        products.add(createdUserProduct);

        System.out.println("Du la till:");
        System.out.println(createdUserProduct);
    }

    public void searchCatalog() {
        do {
            System.out.print("Ange ett nyckelord: ");
            String searchTerm = input.nextLine().trim();

            if (searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Ange ett giltigt nyckelord för att söka.");
                return;
            }

            List<Product> matching = products.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.hasTerm(searchTerm))
                .toList();
            if (matching.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Inga sökresultat hittades.");
            } else {
                for (Product catalog: matching) {
                    System.out.println("Resultatet av din sökning:");
                    System.out.print(catalog);
                    System.out.print("Vill du beräkna priset för produkten? ");
                    if (askYesNo()) {
                        System.out.print("Vänligen ange antal: ");
                        int userChoiceQuantity = input.nextInt();
                        input.nextLine();
                        calculatePrice(userChoiceQuantity, catalog.price());
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.print("Vill du gå ur huvudmenyn? ");
        } while (!askYesNo());
    }

    public void browseCatalog() {
        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("""
Välkommen till produktkatalogen; vill du:
1. Bläddra i katalogen.
2. Sök i katalogen.
3. Gå tillbaka till huvudmenyn.
""");
            switch (input.nextLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    filterCatalogByCategories();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    searchCatalog();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void filterCatalogByCategories() {
        System.out.println("Kategorialternativ:");
        for (ProduceType primaryType: ProduceType.values()) {
            System.out.println(primaryType);
        }
        System.out.print("Välj bland alternativen: ");
        ProduceType firstChoice;
        try {
            firstChoice = ProduceType.fromName(input.nextLine());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return;
        }

        Set<String> allCategories = products.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.produceType() == firstChoice)
            .map(Product::secondaryType)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
        System.out.println("Kategorialternativ:");
        for (String secondaryType: allCategories) {
            System.out.println(secondaryType);
        }
        System.out.print("Välj bland alternativen: ");
        String secondChoice = input.nextLine();
        if (allCategories.contains(secondChoice)) {
            System.out.println("Fullständiga produkter:");
            products.stream()
                .filter(p ->
                    p.produceType() == firstChoice && secondChoice.equals(p.secondaryType())
                )
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    public void removeProduct() {
        do {
            System.out.print("Ange namnet på produkten du vill ta bort: ");
            String userChoice = input.nextLine();

            Map<Boolean, List<Product>> matches = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                    p -> p.name().equalsIgnoreCase(userChoice)
                ));

            if (matches.get(true).isEmpty())
                System.out.println("Denna produkt finns inte.");
            else {
                products.clear();
                products.addAll(matches.get(true));
                for (Product removedProduct: matches.get(false)) {
                    System.out.printf("Du tog bort %s.%n", removedProduct.name());
                }
            }

            System.out.print("Gå tillbaka till huvudmenyn? ");
        } while (!askYesNo());
    }

    public void printAllProducts() {
        for (Product allProducts: products) {
            System.out.println(allProducts);
        }
    }

    public void calculatePrice(int quantity, double price) {
        double sum = quantity * price;
        System.out.printf("Det totala priset blir: %s.%n",
            currFormat.format(sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (;;)` hurts my eyes :) why not just use a boolean with a do-while? That way you can give it a sensible name as well.